# Bash script with ssh ocassional bug

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a script which is doing ssh to a server and checking heap memory utilization of some java processes. However every now and then it seems the script does not have the expected behaviour.
The relevant part is the below :

```
 else
            result_line=$(ssh -q -T "$service_host" 2> /dev/null <<EOF
            #Get the -Xmx value (eg 4G or 128M etc)
            xmx=\$(ps aux | grep $service_pid | grep -v grep | awk -F'Xmx' '{print \$NF}' |cut -d' ' -f1)
            #GB or MB ?
            m_g=\${xmx: -1}

            if [ \$m_g == "m" ] || [ \$m_g == "M" ]
            then 
                    #It's MB, no conversion needed
                    service_xmx=\${xmx::len-1}
            else
                    #It's GB, so convert to MB
                    gb=\${xmx::len-1}
                    service_xmx=\$(awk "BEGIN {print \$gb * 1024}")
            fi
            name=$service_name
            jstat_output=\$(jstat -gc $service_pid | grep -v S0C)
            a=( \$jstat_output )
            usage_KB=\$(echo "scale=2;\${a[2]} + \${a[3]} + \${a[5]} + \${a[7]} + \${a[9]} + \${a[11]}" | bc)
            usage_MB=\$(echo "scale=2; \$usage_KB / 1024" | bc)

            usage_perc=\$(awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.1f\n\", \$usage_MB / \$service_xmx * 100}")

            paste <(printf %-32s "\$name") <(printf %16s "$service_host") <(printf %14s "\$usage_MB") <(printf %14s "\$service_xmx") <(printf %15s "\$usage_perc %%")

EOF
    )
    printf "$result_line\n"

    fi
```

The script seems to occasionally failing to convert a service Xmx from GB to MB, and as such giving wrong heap utilization percentage. Specifically it happened on a service with -Xmx4g , and did not convert it to MB so `$service_xmx` ended up with value 4. **This rarely happens, but happens**.. The part doing the conversion is the below :

```
else
      gb=\${xmx::len-1}
      service_xmx=\$(awk "BEGIN {print \$gb * 1024}")
```

The issue is not systematic, I am unable to reproduce and really struggling to understand why this part fails occassionally... any idea anyone ?

Many thanks

Comment: Just to add that I have added a dirty fix to fix the conversion on the spot if such issue is noticed : 
`if [[ \$service_xmx -lt 128 ]]; then service_xmx=\$(awk "BEGIN {print \$service_xmx * 1024}"); fi`  .. But I would really like to understand why such issue occurs in first place..

Comment: @andrew surely not... $gb * 1024 gives megabytes.  $gb / 1024 would give terabytes

Comment: Start by copy/pasting your script into http://shellcheck.net and fixing the issues it tells you about as the `bash` tag you used instructs you to do. If you still have a problem afterwards then post a question with a [mcve], not just a small section of some larger script where the problem might be in part of the code we can't see.

Comment: just as a note you can change your awk part in the beginig to already do the g/m correction: `awk -F'Xmx' '{m=gensub("[gmGM] .*","",1,$NF); if ($NF ~ /^[0-9]*[Gg]/) m = m*1024; else if ($NF ~ /^[0-9]*[kK]/) m=m/1024;  print m  }'`

Comment: 1) Are you sure Xmx is always given? 2) probably better to give `-Xmx` as  awk field separator.(less of a chance to appear somewhere else) 3) if always given can it only be `m` or `g`? or can it also be `k` or nothing?

Comment: @Lutz 1) Yes it's always given 2) will try 3) in my case it is always given and it's either only megabytes (M or m) or gigabytes (G or g).

Comment: @EdMorton will try your suggestions, however not sure how could I post a "minimal reproducible example" - as explained the issue is not (easily) reproducible  as it seems to work as expected 99.9% of the time

Comment: Your code right now is a chunk starting with `else` out of the middle of a shell script. We can't even try executing that. Reduce it to just the code that populates `result_line` then prints it, add the shebang you're using followed by code setting the variables you use (I see `service_host` and `service_pid` at least) to representative values, sample output of `ps aux` that your code should produce output for, sample contents of any files being parsed or output of any other commands, and finally add the expected output given all of that. Then we'll have a [mcve] to work with.

Comment: One immediate thought is - why are you doing all that work inside the `ssh` session with all the extra complexity that brings instead of just calling `ps aux` and `jstat` inside `ssh` and then doing all of the real work in your local shell on the output of that simple `ssh` command?

Comment: Which variables are you _intentionally_ passing into your remote script? It'd be a lot easier to read and work with if you changed `<<EOF` to `<<'EOF'` so you no longer need to change each `$` to `\$` &c; when you _need_ to pass a variable, that can be done on the command line.

Comment: BTW, note that in general, substituting variables into an awk script (or anything else that's going to be parsed as code) is a Bad Idea. Much better practice to use `awk -v`, or feed values on stdin, or so forth; that way you avoid injection vulnerabilities.